# ASP.NET Core How to read config properties as I do in a Spring?

Tags: asp.net, spring, web-config

I'm very newbie with ASP.NET, but not with Spring (Java).

I was wondering how the ASP.NET Core applications are normally configured ? The place I used before for my config in a web applications was application.properties (or others  under /src/main/resources cause I used allways maven) and later I just had to add @Configuration Bean referencing the attributes in the POJO.

So is there a similiar way to do config stuff onLoad time on ASP.NET ? (easily)
How do you normally configure a ASP.NET  or Where do you put the configuration files ? 
How is the right way to do it ? Do you normally have a schema of files and directories to follow ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Class 
using System.Configuration;
private string varName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];

Web.config
<appSettings>
    <add key="key" value="vaue" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Hi, it seems like I dont have a "Web.config" file but I have a "appsettings.json" I will try something similiar with this other file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a late answer here, but the approach in ASP.NET Core is to use [.NET Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) abstractions, including `IOptions` which is detailed on the same page. There are providers for application.json, environment variables and a variety of other options.

Coming from Spring, you may also be interested in [config providers offered by Steeltoe](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v3/configuration/), probably most notably options for using Spring Cloud Config Server